# Retrive AppId in webservice from webconnector

Tags: quickbooks

My task is to integrate Quick Books 2015 enterprise with my web application. I created a web service to handle web connector call. I install web connector in client computer where Quick Books 2015 enterprise is running. I created  a .qwc file to add application.

Everything is OK. I added a AppID in .qwc. I need to retrive AppID in any WebService method ie. authenticate etc. How can i get that?

Answer (score 0):

QBWC client will push the username and password to you for authentication.

See https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/doc/PDF/QBWC_proguide.pdf for more information on QBWC.

AppID is not used and can be blank.